# Git pull origin/master branch to local/master, when in local/develop

Tags: git, branch

I work in develop branch. Sometimes, when I want to push changes to origin, git say, that there are some changes in origin/master branch.

How to pull changes from remote master to local master without checkout to local master?

Comment: Some more answers in a possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18994609/how-to-git-pull-into-a-branch-that-is-not-the-current-one

Comment: @Olga that question is similar, but is focused on `git fetch`, and generally not merging any code into your current branch.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

If you want to update your local master without checkout, you can do :

```
git pull origin master:master
```

That will update your local master with the `origin/master`

Or, as I assume that you want to ultimately rebase your `develop` branch with the changes occured in `origin/master`, you can do a simple `git fetch`, that will not touch your local branches :

```
git fetch
```

Now your `origin/master`is up to date, so you can rebase or merge your local branch with these changes. For example, when you are in your `develop` branch :

```
git rebase origin/master
```

And your develop branch will be up to date with the changes.

Comment: `git pull origin master:master` also pulls changes to your local develop branch

Comment: Then either this answer should include the impact on local branch or modify the answer to something else. I would ask the original acceptor of this answer needs to unmark first and verify to give accept again.

Comment: This answer is wrong. `git pull origin master:master` starts a rebase on my local

Answer (score 0):

Accepted answer will also pulls master into your actual branch.

```
git fetch
git branch -D master
git checkout --track origin/master
```