# How to 'git pull' into a branch that is not the current one?

Tags: git, branch, git-branch

When you run `git pull` on the `master` branch, it typically pulls from `origin/master`.  I am in a different branch called `newbranch`, but I need to run a command that does a `git pull` from `origin/master` into `master` but I cannot run `git checkout` to change the selected branch until after the pull is complete.  Is there a way to do this?

To give some background, the repository stores a website.  I have made some changes in `newbranch` and deployed them by switching the website to `newbranch`.  Now those changes have been merged upstream into the `master` branch, I am trying to switch the website back to the `master` branch as well.  At this point, `newbranch` and `origin/master` are identical, but `master` is lagging behind `origin/master` and needs to be updated.  The problem is, if I do it the traditional way:

```
$ git checkout master
   # Uh oh, production website has now reverted back to old version in master
$ git pull
   # Website is now up to date again
```

I need to achieve the same as above (`git checkout master && git pull`), but without changing the working directory to an earlier revision during the process.

Comment: @phi: I don't think it would work, because I'm in `newbranch` and there's nothing there to stash!

Comment: I would clone into a fresh directory, merge newbranch into master, merge master back into newbranch, then git pull from where you are. Master and newbranch will be the same.

Comment: @aet He could just do that now in his current directory by doing `git fetch; git merge origin/master` from within `newbranch`. There is zero benefit to cloning an entire second copy of the repository.

Comment: Upstream has already done a fast-forward merge on `master` so `newbranch` and `master` already are the same.  The problem is I can't switch to the `master` branch without going back a dozen commits (losing many files in the working directory) and then doing a `git pull` (restoring things to the state they are in now.)

Comment: closely related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216360/merge-update-and-pull-git-branches-without-using-checkouts

Comment: I found the answer that worked for me in another stackoverflow post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216360/merge-update-and-pull-git-branches-without-using-checkouts Basically: `git fetch <remote> <srcBranch>:<destBranch>`

Comment: Maybe consider changing the accepted answer to mine below?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge, update, and pull Git branches without using checkouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216360/merge-update-and-pull-git-branches-without-using-checkouts)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got a worktree you don't want to touch, so use another one.  Clone is cheap, it's built for this.

```
git fetch origin master       # nice linear tree
git clone . ../wip -b master  # wip's `origin/master` is my `master`
cd ../wip                     # .
git pull origin origin/master # merge origin's origin/master
git push origin master        # job's done, turn it in.
cd ../main
rm -rf ../wip                 # wip was pushed here, wip's done

git checkout master           # payload
```

The problem with all the other answers here is, they don't actually do the pull. If you need the merge or rebase you've got pull set up for, you need another worktree and the above procedure. Otherwise just `git fetch; git checkout -B master origin/master` will do.

Comment: When you run `git checkout master` you'll checkout the old `master` branch because you haven't done a `git pull` in the `main` folder to synchronise it with origin/master.  This is what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: The checkout done by the clone is of the old master, but that checkout is into a directory the webserver's not looking at.  The master checkout at the end is of the fully merged master that was pushed back from wip.

Comment: On line 6 you push the merged (updated) `master` back to `origin`, but I don't believe your final checkout is of this updated `master`.  There is no `git pull` to update the `master` branch in the `main` directory, so unless I am missing something your commands are no different from just running `git checkout master` on its own and getting the old `master` tree.  If you look closely, you are not running any commands in the `main` directory that communicate upstream (apart from line 1, which is run before you made any changes to the upstream repo.)

Comment: well, you could try it on a test repo, or check the push docs.

Comment: Well when I try it at line 5 I get the error `fatal: 'origin/wip' does not appear to be a git repository` but I realise my misunderstanding.  When you push to `origin` you're pushing to the repository *in* `main` - I was thinking you were pushing to main's origin instead, forgetting that `git clone` is not an identical copy, the upstream branches are different.  So I see what you are doing is instead of pulling into the target branch, you are pushing into it from outside.

Comment: That's right, and I should have said at the time both sorry for the error in my script and thanks for the correction and staying with it.

Comment: @jwg compared to what, please?  Do be sure to address all OP's stated needs.

Comment: @jwg I second jthill comment. What are the alternatives. Your comment as it stands it's not constructive.

Answer (score 210):

Straightforward: Updating from a remote branch into a currently not checked-out branch *master*:

```
git fetch origin master:master
```

where *origin* is your remote and you are currently checked out in some branch e.g. *dev*.

If you want to update your current branch in addition to the specified branch at one go:

```
git pull origin master:master
```

Comment: Hm, it seems it doesn't always work, though; I just got prompted to merge with my WIP branch.

Comment: @underscore_d same for me.

Comment: Worked for me...if it prompts to merge then I imagine there are changes in your branch that you are updating that are not committed to the origin

Comment: How is this supposed to work? It doesn't work for me, it just tries to merge origin/master into my currently checked-out branch.

Comment: This pulls master into the current branch.  This is definitely NOT what is being asked for.  If you change pull to fetch, then this would be exactly what is being asked for.

Comment: is `git fetch origin master:master` going to overwrite local `master` branch with the remote version no matter what or there is some kind of protection that blocks you from doing it if the change is not fast-forward?

Answer (score 108):

This is answered here:
[Merge, update, and pull Git branches without using checkouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216360/merge-update-and-pull-git-branches-without-using-checkouts)

```
# Merge local branch foo into local branch master,
# without having to checkout master first.
# Here `.` means to use the local repository as the "remote":
git fetch . foo:master

# Merge remote branch origin/foo into local branch foo,
# without having to checkout foo first:
git fetch origin foo:foo
```

Comment: This is the best, as it works with uncommitted local changes.

Comment: If you just want to catch up with the latest changes you'd do `git fetch origin master:master`. `git fetch` by itself would assume you meant to update the current branch and not some other branch.

Comment: This is the simplest and most direct answer. This should be the accepted answer IMO.

Comment: @JohnLeidegren - except it does not always work as intended. See comments to https://stackoverflow.com/a/42902058/274579 answer.

Comment: If you want to fetch everything from origin like `git pull` does, you can do `git fetch; git fetch origin foo:foo`. But is there a better way?

Answer (score 24):

As it turns out, the answer is deceptively simple:

```
$ git fetch                           # Update without changing any files
$ git branch -d master                # Remove out-of-date 'master' branch
$ git checkout --track origin/master  # Create and check out up-to-date 'master' branch
```

This allows you to update the `master` branch without switching to it until *after* it has been updated.

Comment: This doesn't do what you asked how to do.

Comment: As the comment above says, the question you wound up asking isn't really the question you wound up having answered. You should update your question so that it's less specifically about merging into a branch without checking it out, and more about moving directly to the newest version of a branch available on a remote without checking out the old version first.

Comment: My question was about how to do a pull before a checkout, which is what this achieves.  I will edit the question for clarity but having re-read the question, this answer does exactly what I asked!

Comment: It's absolutely the answer I came here looking for :)

Comment: Not what OP wanted, but helped me, to be honest.

Comment: Fixed in my case. Thanks

Comment: @anoniim, not what the OP wanted? You mean the OP that just answered this question?

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for a(n IDE-friendly) command that I can use right after the merge request of my feature branch is merged in GitLab :-)

Answer (score 12):

You're worried about something that cannot be fixed, as Git operations are not atomic. You will always have a hole where your working directory is **half way** between branches, even if you update master without first switching to it. This is why *Git is not a deployment tool*.

Since you're not actually committing code in your production environment (I hope), you don't actually *need* to have a branch checked out. You can simply do a `git fetch` to update your remote refs, and then `git checkout origin/master` to move the working directory *directly* to the commit currently pointed to by `origin/master`. This will put you in a detached head state, but again, as you're not committing code, this doesn't matter.

This is the smallest hole you're going to get, but as I said, a hole still exists; `checkout` is not atomic.

Comment: I understand the limitations of using git for deployment, the problem is that the hole in this case is going to be minutes long instead of less than one second.  Nice idea about checking out `origin/master` though, that might just do the trick.

Comment: What makes the hole "minutes" long? Pulling data across the network? Just do a `git fetch` before you do anything else and get the actual transfer of data out of the way.

Comment: It's minutes long because a (now) untracked file would be overwritten by an earlier commit.  So I have to copy the file, do the git stuff, then put it back.  The 'minutes long' comes from my typing speed.  (Yes I could script it but it was just to make a point that having git do everything itself is faster.)

Answer (score 4):

You can use update-ref for this:

```
git fetch
git update-ref refs/heads/master origin/master
git checkout master
```

Note that this would throw away any local commits in the master branch. In your case there won't be any so this is okay. For other people trying to do this where there are local commits, I don't think it's possible, since merge can only be run on the current branch.

Comment: Would this be equivalent to `git branch --force master origin/master`? This forces the local head `master` to point to the head of `origin`s `master`

Answer (score 4):

`git fetch origin master:master`

- "Pulls" (actually fetches) `master`.
- If you have changes on your `master` that aren't pushed yet, `origin/master` is merged into your master.
- If there are merge conflicts, you'll have to solve them first.

Answer (score 2):

Malvineous's solution work for me

> ```
> $ git fetch                           # Update without changing any files
> $ git branch -d master                # Remove out-of-date 'master' branch
> $ git checkout --track origin/master  # Create and check out up-to-date 'master' branch
> ```

Just in give the error

```
warning: not deleting branch 'master' that is not yet merged to
         'refs/remotes/origin/master', even though it is merged to HEAD.
error: The branch 'master' is not fully merged.
If you are sure you want to delete it, run 'git branch -D master'.
```

So i run with -D option

thanks