# Git push of an Overleaf project to a different branch other than master

Tags: git, commit

I'd like to push changes of an overleaf project to multiple branches besides the master on Git. Would that be possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by "overleaf" you mean that Git repository project has multiple sub-project as [submodules](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule), then said overleaf project can:

- [loop over its submodules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19729595/6309)
- push its `master` to any branch it wants for each submodule subrepo.

But if it is the opposite, meaning a subproject derived from the overleaf project knows about said overleaf project (and the overleaf one has no idea of how many subprojects there are), then you need a script which, in each subproject repo, would fetch the main [project `master` branch -- for instance -- to any local branch you need](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45697574/6309).

```
git fetch mainProject master:myBranch
```

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the Overleaf web UI only cares about the main branch:

> Known Limitations
>
> Branches: The Overleaf Git system does not support branching.

Source: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Using_Git_and_GitHub

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understand your need, but I would like to share my solution.

Suppose I have a Git repo, which contains folders `src` (source code), `note` (tex files), `res`, etc for a project. All folders are synced to GitHub. But I want to only sync the `note` folder to the overleaf.

Without creating another repo for overleaf, I create a branch named `paper`, and sync it with overleaf.

#### Step 1: create `paper` branch

```
git checkout --orphan paper
```

where `--orphan` creates a new branch, but it starts without any commit.

In the `paper` branch, remove other folders and only keep the `note` folder.

#### Step 2: add overleaf as another remote repo

Follow the [official instruction from overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Using_Git_and_GitHub#Creating_an_Overleaf_project_from_an_existing_Git_repository) to obtain the git link at overleaf, then add it as a remote repo

```
git remote add overleaf https://git.overleaf.com/XXXXXXXXXXX
```

#### Step 3: git pull & push

Note that the default branch on overleaf is `master`, but our local repo branch is `paper`. We can set the upstream for tracking the changes,

```
$ git branch --set-upstream-to=overleaf/master paper 
Branch 'paper' set up to track remote branch 'master' from 'overleaf'
$ git pull
```

To push local changes, we need to specify the local and remote branch names `paper:master`.

```
$ git push overleaf paper:master
```

Answer (score 0):

I have linked Overleaf with Dropbox. Now I can use git traditionally via the local Dropbox integration. If you change the branch you have to wait for Dropbox to sync, then you will also see the changes in Overleave.