# How to pull develop without removing files deleted in develop in Git?

Tags: git

I got pulled off of one task A to fix an urgent bug - task B.

I created a new branch for task B but that contained some new files that I was working on from task A (I messed up the branch creation here I guess). Both branches were based on develop.

Anyway when it came to create the pull request for task B I deleted the new (task A) files committed then created the pull request.

So now I want to pull for develop. I know this will update my task A branch - so will probably delete the new files I created.

How do I do the equivalent of:

```
git pull origin develop
```

while keeping the new files?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to 'git pull' into a branch that is not the current one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18994609/how-to-git-pull-into-a-branch-that-is-not-the-current-one)

Comment: I suspected there would already be an answer, but searching came up with a LOT of answers most of which weren't relevant.

Comment: And is that one?

Comment: Not 100%, but its given me enough of an idea to get things working).

Comment: Pro tip: the community has [discussed adding home-made tags to titles](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253028), and has agreed we'd rather titles were sentences or questions in ordinary English. Keywords can either be fitted into titles in an organic fashion, or saved for the tags proper. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start by cloning a clean workspace.  Checkout the correct point where the task B branch was supposed to be located.  Create a branch, task B2.  Now merge in changes from your bad branch into the new branch.

After you have everything the way you like, then you can delete the previously created task B branch.

Comment: I think I'll create a backup branch of my my task A. Do the pull on task A then cherry pick from the backup to restore the deleted files. (Our build system likes to have specific name formats, so its nice to use the one I have for task A).