# Branch Y from branch X - how to refresh only original branch X?

Tags: git

I have checked out a Git branch: `git checkout branch_x`. Than I made **a branch from a branch**: `git checkout -b branch_y branch_x`. I then work in new `branch_y`, make some changes, etc, than I want to pull changes that happened in original `branch_x` just to see what's going on. So while in `branch_y` I do:

`git pull origin branch_x`

But his fails with a message:

`error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge. Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge. Aborting.`

I expected that `git pull origin branch_x` would have absolutely no effect on my own new `branch_y`.

Can I avoid this automatic merge and pull the changes only into `branch_x`?

Comment: `git pull` means *run `git fetch`, then run a second Git command.* The second command defaults to `git merge`. If you don't want to run `git merge`, don't run `git pull` at all: just run only the *first* command. Run it yourself: `git fetch`. This will update your `origin/branch_x` without touching your own `branch_x`. To make `git fetch` touch your own `branch_x`, see [fham_526's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62083545/1256452).

Comment: Note that if you don't plan to make any of your own *commits*, you do not need your own `branch_x` either. Just use `origin/branch_x` everywhere you would have used `branch_x`. Since you won't *have* a `branch_x` you won't feel any need to *update* it either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bring changes from origin/branch_x into branch_x without checkout using:

```
git fetch origin branch_x:branch_x
```

as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42902058/7018635).

Comment: This fetched the changes but I don’t think it merges them. I would expect that a checkout and merge would to still need to happen.

Comment: that command will update your local `branch_x` to whatever is there in `origin/branch_x`, i.e. it will merge remote changes onto your local branch (but only if it's a fast-forward, otherwise you can force a non-fast-forward merge with `git fetch origin +branch_x:branch_x`). This works only if your current branch is anything other than `branch_x`

Comment: @evolutionxbox It doesn't merge, it fast-forwards. If it cannot fast-forward (there're not yet pushed commits in the branch locally) it fails loudly so the user knows she should merge or rebase.